# How to close the pop-up window when accessing the Telegram channel from the web?

Tags: node.js, web-crawler, puppeteer

For example, I accessed https://t.me/movocashtransfers. A pop-up window appears asking if you want to open the Telegram app. I want to close this because I have to close it to crawl web information.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function test () {
  try {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
    })
    let page = await browser.newPage()
    let override = Object.assign(page.viewport(), { width: 1920, height: 1080 })
    await page.setViewport(override)

    page.on('dialog', async dialog => {
      console.log(dialog.message())
      await dialog.dismiss()
      let channelMembers = document.querySelectorAll('.tgme_page.tgme_page_post .tgme_page_extra')[0].innerHTML

      console.log('channelMembers:', channelMembers)
    })

    await page.goto(`https://t.me/movocashtransfers`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('e:', e)
  }
}

test()
```

This is what the pop-up looks like:

[image]

Comment: After accessing await page.goto(`https://t.me/movocashtransfers`, {waitUntil:'networkidle0' }) I want to close the popup to get the web information.

Comment: The dialog message is like this.

Would you like to open Telegram?
I am trying to open this application at https://t.me.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any other 'normal' solution than press 'Escape'

```
const robot = require('robotjs');
robot.keyTap('escape');
```

Comment: Puppeteer: [Bug]: dialog handler doesn't catch "open with application" popup #9122 (still open)